# dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier creates a cell with nil subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a subclass of UICollectionViewCell **with a .xib**, and when creating it in

```
- (CategoryViewCollectionCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       CategoryViewCollectionCell *cell = 
 [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryViewCollectionCell" 
                               forIndexPath:indexPath];

       .....   
 }
```

The cell is a valid CategoryViewCollectionCell with all the properties, but they all are nil.

Comment: Have you registered your `CategoryViewCollectionCell` for your `UICollectionView`? Example: `[self.collectionView registerClass:[CategoryViewCollectionCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryViewCollectionCell"];`

Comment: No. Registration you should do, if you are not using xib. I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour when the cell is dequeued for the first time. In the following lines in this method you should be taking actions to set the properties of the `CategoryViewCollectionCell` objects to appropriate values based on the index path.

If you are using a xib to design your custom cell, make sure you register it using `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` after the collection view is instantiated and make sure all of the necessary outlets are hooked up to the properties, and make sure that the class of the cell in the xib matches `CategoryViewCollectionCell`.

Comment: I have a xib for that. The text of the label should be nil, but the label shouldn't be, after all it is created already in the xib

Comment: Make sure you register your xib using `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` after the collection view is instantiated. Take a look at my updated answer and see if you're doing all those things.